# c# can't write to file after creating it

Tags: c#, file

My problem is really simple. I create a file, and I can't write to it. BUT if I close the program then re-open when the file is created, it doesn't throw any exceptions. I think when the `File.Create` method runs, the program locks it.
`path` is just a location of a txt file. When I try to delete the file manually, it says my program using it.

```
if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path);

try
{
    File.WriteAllLines(path, new string[] {"hi"});
}
catch(IOException)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Remove `File.Create(path);`: you don't want `FileStream` created (which put an exclusive lock on the file)

Comment: File.WriteAllLines creates, opens and writes the lines and closes the file. Remove File.Create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want

```
File.Create(path);
```

Since it creates `FileStream` which put an exlusive lock on the file. All you need is `File.WriteAllLines`:

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllLines(path, new string[] {"hi"});
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

In case you want to be sure that all *subdirectories* within `path` are created you should create the directory, not the file:

```
try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

    File.WriteAllLines(path, new string[] {"hi"});
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```